# how to force break words that exceed width of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am running into an issue that i do not think is possible with css. i have a text output dynamically showing in a label that only has the following html

`label {
width:94px;
}`

i am trying to come up with a solution that will dynamically take any mutliple word that exceeds the width of the div, and force break that word. if a word is to be split but could fit on its own line without breaking within the text, then wrap it to the next line

an example of this working fine as is would be the following screenshot:
[image]

here is the current scenario where a letter inside a word is pushed to the next line:
[image]

here is what i would like to happen in this scenario:
[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated. i am very curious if this is even possible with css without a lot of hacks and cross-browser issues...

Comment: unfortunately that does not solve the problem

Comment: We'd need to see your HTML and existing CSS to really help...

Comment: Can you please try to give us a jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it should wrap (example 1)

use `word-break: keep-all;` (example 2)

But when a word is too long you need to use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` (example 3)

```css
p {
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p.test1 {
  word-break: keep-all;
}

p.test2 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">This paragraph contains some text. This line will-break-at-hyphens. verylongtextnonstoplolstillnotdonesorry</p>

<p class="test1">This paragraph contains some text. This line will-break-at-hyphens. verylongtextnonstoplolstillnotdonesorry</p>

<p class="test2">This paragraph contains some text. The lines will break at any character. verylongtextnonstoplolstillnotdonesorry</p>
```

Comment: yes seems i had `word-break, word-wrap, white-space` over-riding the style and thus messing it up. i appreciate your help.

Comment: @HollerTrain also make sure use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` if the word is too long, you might still want to break the word if it is causing overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [word-wrap:break-word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap?v=control); would do the job

Comment: if i could upload a screenshot to this comment i would to help illustrate, but your solution would not work. the concept of this task at hand is to manually push the second or more word that currently breaks and results in being pushed to end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css, your line break will now depend on the `width` of `span`

```css
span{
  width:20%;
  display:flex;
  background-color:yellow;
}

div{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div><span>how to force break words</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try ***word-wrap:break-word;*** or  ***word-break:break-all;***